# can't access array values because my int is not convertible

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to access an array in a Class with a value from another class, but when I try to call the array, it says that Int is not convertible to Range. The way I'm calling it is this

```
let position:Int = Int(note.positionPicker)

note.position = CGPointMake(player.legalPositions[position],self.frame.height + note.size)
```

On the second line it gives the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (my syntax might not be 100% xcode not on this comp.)

```
 let pos:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:44,y:66) //X, y whatever you want.
```

all you need to do is get the x/y coords from `note.positionPicker` and plug into `position`

```
 let position:CGPoint = CGPoint(note.positionPicker.x, note.positionPicker.y) //this depends on how you created positionPicker.
```

You can then access the x/y value like so(if you need to):

```
 let x = position.x // 44
 let y = position.y // 66
```

Comment: When I make position a float, it says 'Float' is not convertible to 'Int'

Comment: Try CGFloat since as you can see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointMake. Make sure you are passing everything in as CGfloats.

Comment: @Murturn if my answer helped you please mark this as accepted. If not please let me know where you are stuck and ill try to help :)